# From where does the 'self' attribute in Django get its instance?

Tags: python, django, instance, self

I'm trying get a grip working around Django and Python. I've always been puzzled with what the `self` parameter in functions is.

Example:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Your Email')
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', \
                    widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password Confirmation', \
                    widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']

    def clean_password2(self):
        print "Inside clean_password2:"
        print self
        print "_________________________________________________"
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
        return password2
```

The output in the terminal is:

```
[02/Jul/2015 15:03:26]"GET /accounts/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5118
Inside clean_password2:
<tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td><input id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" value="TestUser" /><br /><span class="helptext">Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</span></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_email">Your Email:</label></th><td><input id="id_email" name="email" type="email" value="test@test.com" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_password1">Password:</label></th><td><input id="id_password1" name="password1" type="password" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_password2">Password Confirmation:</label></th><td><input id="id_password2" name="password2" type="password" /></td></tr>
```

Which is to say, `self` attribute is whatever displayed above. Question is, Where is this function and the self attribute getting this from?

I'm not asking about the role of `self` as a language feature of python. My question is squarely on how `self` gets an instance in Django.

The repository of which this code a part of is [here](https://github.com/ShubhamRathi/Django-ecommerce).

TL;DR: Why is all that HTML printed when I print self. Where is that coming from?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python

Comment: I hear some people say "explicit is better than implicit"

Comment: @TheGeorgeous: This question isnt a duplicate of what you've shown. I'm not asking about the role of self as a language feature of python. My question is squarely on how self gets an instance in Django. In a very razor sharp case, the example which I have mentioned. 
In case you still find it to be a duplicate, please give a brief answer to it. The question closes.

Comment: @user248884, self doesn't 'get' an instance. It is just a convention in Python when a class refers to itself. So when you print self, what you get are the instance attributes defined for that particular class. If your question is how it got converted to html, check django's ModelForm class

Comment: What on earth do you mean *"how `self` gets an instance"*? You have an instance somewhere, say `my_registration_form`, so when `my_registration_form.clean_password2()` gets called `self` **is that instance**. If your question is how Django instantiates and manages the classes you define, that's way too broad for SO.

Comment: Lets make the question a lil' more clear and blunt. Why is all that HTML printed when I print self. Where is that coming from?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, when you print `self`, you are printing the `ModelForm` instance.

When you print an object in Python, it calls the `__str__` method of the object.

If you look at the [`__str__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d92b08536d873c0966e8192e64d8e8bd9de79ebe/django/forms/forms.py#L134) method of the Form class, it calls the [`as_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#as-table) method, which displays the fields as the contents of an html table. This is the output you are seeing.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.as_table()
```

Comment: Just a thing, There is no def __str__(self) corresponding to this model. You could see the repository too. Then where is it coming from?

Comment: `self` is a **form** instance, not a model instance. I've linked to the form's `__str__`,  and included the code in my answer above.

Comment: Right. From where is the form instance coming? To ask, Which part of Django is sending that HTML as a form instance.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. In the method where you call `print self`, `self` is a form instance. The print statement is calling `str(self)`, which calls `self.__str__()`, then displays the output. I don't know what you mean by 'which part is sending'.